# Could not find module, it is a member of the hidden package haskell98

Tags: haskell, import, hidden

When I try to compile a simple source file with `import IO` or `import Random`, the build fails with an error message like this:

```
Could not find module 'IO'
It is a member of the hidden package 'haskell98-2.0.0.1'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for
```

Answer (score 25):

The module names changed at some point.  You probably want `import System.IO` and `import System.Random` instead.

Here is the [module hierarchy](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/libraries/index.html) for the standard libraries in GHC 7.6.1.

Comment: Alternatively, compile with `-package haskell98 -hide-package base -hide-package array`.